# Add image and line break within a table

Tags: tables, graphics, line-breaking

I want to create a rather mysterious table with both a line brake in a single row and an image. You understand that I cannot use a new row without `\hline` because I want to add an image at the same row. I tried with `\newline` within the cell but it didn't work.

The code that I using is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicols}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\eng{NIM}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Χρήσιμα}} &     \textbf{Εικόνα}\\
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\eng{Module}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}    {\textbf{Χαρακτηριστικά}} & {}\\
\hline
PSU \newline CAEN N1470 & $4$ channels \newline Positive/Ouput Polarity &         \includegraphics[height=\columnheight]{N1470.jpg}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I've only added one row in the MWE just to make it as simple as possible. Note that `\newline` does nothing actually on that very code and `\columnheight` is not recognised at all.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\parbox`es of the required width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
\hline
\parbox{3cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470} 
  & \parbox{3cm}{$4$ channels \\ Positive/Ouput Polarity} 
  & \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{ctanlion}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding `\columnheight` it is not a standard length, so it won't be recognized.

Using the optional argument for `\parbox` and the `adjustbox` package, one can easily comtrol the vertical alignment of the text and the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}
\hline
\parbox[t]{3cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470} 
  & \parbox[t]{3cm}{$4$ channels \\ Positive/Ouput Polarity} 
  & \adjustimage{height=2.5cm,valign=t}{ctanlion} \\
\hline
\parbox{3cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470} 
  & \parbox{3cm}{$4$ channels \\ Positive/Ouput Polarity} 
  & \adjustimage{height=2.5cm,valign=c}{ctanlion} \\
\hline
\parbox[b]{3cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470} 
  & \parbox[b]{3cm}{$4$ channels \\ Positive/Ouput Polarity} 
  & \adjustimage{height=2.5cm,valign=b}{ctanlion} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}
\label{tab:}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Youw solution is partially working. I made some changes, like `\parbox[][][c]{2.5cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470}` instead of `\parbox{2.5cm}{PSU \\ CAEN N1470}` because text was placed on cell's bottom. The trichy thing is the image... If I use your code, it is placed in the bottom of the cell which is not beautiful. I tried to use a parbox again (something like `\parbox[][][c]{2.5cm}{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{N1470.jpg}}`) but in that case it is placed on the left of the cell, which is again not pretty...

Comment: @Thanos did you see my updated answer? Using `\raisebox` for the image you can get the desired alignment.

Comment: I didn't check...Sorry! I tried to inlude the `\includegraphics{}` within `center` enviroment. The output is really good but there are those ugly spaces around that `\begin{center}` adds. I also tried your `raisebox` which is really good, however the image touches the line below. In addition if I increase image's height, it will be printed in fornt of the upper cell line.

Comment: @Thanos I updated my answer with anew option.

Comment: Oh my God...What a solution!!! The moment I saw it I said "This is guy knows how to manipulate LaTeX"...However...it si not working on my system...It cannot recognise the `height=2.5cm,valign=c` sequence...

Comment: @Thanos seems like you have an outdated version of some packages(s) (particularly `adjustbox`). Try updating the package (or even better, your LaTeX system).

Comment: This is really something that needs to be done at some point...Thank you so much for your time!!!